# if <option> selected, scroll down the page?

Tags: javascript, scroll

Is there anyway i can make that thing ?
so if we scroll an option it will scroll down where i want ?

eg:

```
<select name="test>
<option>a</option>
<option>b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your question is not very clear.  By selecting an option, it scrolls to a certain location on the same page?

Comment: There are many ways to do this - can you post what you've tried so far, so we can help you along?

Comment: Hi guys, i meant eg.: if we select the option a to scroll down at the bottom of page automatically, or to scroll it exactly at the wanted part of scrollbar (maybe using 1 to 100 for identifying how down we want do send it [scrollbar] ) i hope i was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming your mark-up reflects the `select` options, I'd suggest, given the following HTML:

```
<select id="test">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>

<div id="a">
    <p>Contents in #a</p>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <p>Contents in #b</p>
</div>

<div id="c">
    <p>Contents in #c</p>
</div>
```

That you could use:

```
​var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = function(){
    window.location.hash = this.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].value;
};​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QD2xs/).

Or:

```
var select = document.getElementById('test');

select.onchange = function(){
    var id = this.getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].value,
        el = document.getElementById(id),
        top = el.offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo(0,top);
};​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QD2xs/1/).